# Unexpected data found Carbon?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have incoming string date:

```
$date = '09.04.1981';
```

I tried t format this date in DATE (mysql), so I do:

```
return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
```

It returns me an exception:

> "Unexpected data found.\r\nUnexpected data found.\r\nTrailing data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carbon is finicky like this.  Is the field currently set as a date in the model, or casted as such?  This sometimes yields this error.  Here's the doc section that might relate:

> When a column is considered a date, you may set its value to a UNIX
>   timestamp, date string (Y-m-d), date-time string, and of course a
>   DateTime / Carbon instance, and the date's value will automatically be
>   correctly stored in your database:

Not sure if this is going that far, based on your question though.  You may also be able to add a format to the end to test.  IE

```
return Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $date)->format('your format of choice')
```

Also, from comments, check that the format is correct against what you are asking for -- if the wrong format, it will provide too much info and trigger the error above.  Make sure you have `('d.m.y', $date)` in the method as above.

If you are looking to convert, try: `Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d')`

Comment: I tried:  `return Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: Yes, sometimes helpful to try tacking on the end like that to test a change in format.  But that error has happened to me mostly when the model casts the field as a date already.  Is that date a model item, or is this a naked error?

Comment: Sorry - Crazy question, but in your original bit you ask Carbon to format from Y-m-d.  In the comments you do d.m.Y - did you try exactly `return Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $date);`?

Comment: I need convert: d.m.Y to Y-m-d

Comment: That's a different question.  If you've solved the error, then try: `Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d')`.  I'll update the answer to suit